# How to assign a default value to an attr_reader attribute with before_validation in rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a "Topic" model with an attribute called "utid"(unique topic id) inside.
We need assign a value to utid when a topic is created.
Besides, utid should be unique and readonly once the value is given.

Here is an example:

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_reader :utid
  before_validation :gen_utid, on: :create
  validates :utid, presence: true, uniqueness: true

  private
  def gen_utid
    self.utid = RandomToken.genf(32)
  end
end
```

But it always raises an exception when creating a new topic:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Utid can't be blank
```

It seems failed to assign the utid value in gen_utid, but I don't know how to fix it. Can you help me to figure it out or is there any other way to achieve the same requires? Thanks~

Comment: Are you sure `RandomToken.genf(32)` works as expected?

Comment: you are defining attr_reader for utid which only generates a getter(no setter). So when you do self.utid = '', it does nothing

Comment: @BillyChan Yes, I am very sure.

Comment: @Vimsha I think it is the root cause, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: @Vimsha hit the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Vimsha is on the right track...

Instead of:

```
attr_reader :utid
```

Try this:

```
attr_readonly :utid
```

From the Rails docs, "Attributes listed as readonly will be used to create a new record but update operations will ignore these fields."

See here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ReadonlyAttributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-attr_readonly

Comment: Isn't that what you want?  To write to it?